# How to create this plot in python matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have these data from csv file, How can I plot this figure, I don't know the plot name to search, I took a look at [CSD demo on matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/csd_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-csd-demo-py), but I don't know if it's the same as my plot or different type.

[image: plot]

Comment: Just try it, looks like a normal line plot

Comment: No it's not, yours is a simple line plot.

Comment: Yeah, it is just a normal line plot. If you are facing issues in adding labels, use `set_xlabel`, `set_ylabel`, `set_title` for these.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I totally new to matplotlib, how a normal line plotted, I mean should I use line2D? I try this `plt.Line2D(df["date_account_created"])` but it doesn't work

Comment: `Line2D` is an "artist" that would need to be added to an Axes object. I recommend reading the docs for learning how to handle matplotlib's most basic functionality. https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py

Comment: Ok, thanks @PaulH

Answer (score 0):

plot by using plt.plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(date, users, label=data_account_created)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```